# ng2-pdf-viewer getOutline() returns undefined

Tags: angular, types, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

[demo of ng2-pdf-viewer](https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/)

To show the table of content I used getOutline() as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts)

```
    this.pdf.getOutline().then((outline: any[]) => {
      this.dataSource.data = outline;
    });
```

It is working fine [this pdf](http://pdftestfile-160315172246.pdf). But for a few pdf Outline is undefined.
I have implemented this ng2-pdf-viewer for those few pdf only.Please help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got it , While converting docx to pdf while doing SAVE AS - PDF format with go to "option dialogue box" and "tick on headings" this will preserve the headers as bookmarks .Actually the headers was getting removed as bookmark